# Referencing table values from md file in dbt yaml files

Tags: yaml, markdown, github-flavored-markdown, dbt, mkdocs

I have a markdown file with a table in it and I have another dbt schema.yml file which is used to serve and generate docs. Traditionally I enter the table name and column name and description of the column name in schema.yml but now that I think of I'd want to reference the column names from the md document into the yaml file rather than manually entering.

This is how my `doc.md` file looks like

```
{% docs column_description %}

| COLUMN\_NAME                   | DESCRIPTION                                                               |
| ------------------------------ | ------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
| cycle\_id                      | Customer cycle\_id(todays start sleep time to next days start sleep time) |
| user\_id                       | Customers user\_id                                                        |
| yes\_alcohol                   | User consumed alcohol or not                                              |
| blank\_alcohol                 | User did not answer or user answered "No"                                 |
                    


{% enddocs %}
```

And, currently, this is how my schema.yml file looks

```
version: 2

models:

- name: journal_pivot_dev
    description: One for for each journal entry of within one customer cycle
    columns:
      - name: cycle_id
        description:  Customer cycleid
        tests: &not_null
          - not_null:
              severity: warn
      - name: user_id
        description: customer userid
        tests:
          - not_null:
              severity: warn
      - name: yes_alcohol
        description: User consumed alcohol or not
        tests: &values_accepted
          - accepted_values:
              severity: warn
              values: [0,1]
      - name: blank_alcohol
        description: User did not answer          
        tests: *values_accepted
```

What I tried:

```
version: 2
    
    models:
    
    - name: journal_pivot_dev
        description: One for for each journal entry of within one customer cycle
        columns:
          - name: cycle_id
            description:  '{{ doc(column_description") }}'
            tests: &not_null
              - not_null:
                  severity: warn
          - name: user_id
            description: '{{ doc(column_description") }}'
            tests:
              - not_null:
                  severity: warn
          - name: yes_alcohol
            description: '{{ doc(column_description") }}'
            tests: &values_accepted
              - accepted_values:
                  severity: warn
                  values: [0,1]
          - name: blank_alcohol
            description: '{{ doc(column_description") }}'          
            tests: *values_accepted
```

But when I do that the description is not rendering to just cycle_id but it is giving me the whole table in the md file.

[image]

I am expecting something like this

[image]

Comment: please let me know if something about my answer doesn't address your question.

Comment: I think this works and I can build work arounds. Thank you!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TLDR: what you are trying to do is not currently possible given that function.

When you call the `{{ docs('filename.md') }}` function in dbt right now, the code that is being executed (see [`doc()`](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt/blob/develop/core/dbt/context/docs.py#L31) from dbtlabs' github) is just importing the compiled version of the entire markdown file (after making sure that it is a valid, non-zero length markdown of course).

Arguable, this could be better indicated as such in the docs themselves:
https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/resource-properties/description#use-a-docs-block-in-a-description

---

Let's talk alternatives.

How about we create each of your docs and try to import them into a single "aggregate" doc?

So, using a brand new dbt project `my-project` let's see:

New project layout:

```
    | analysis
    | data
    | macros
    | models
         | docs
            | agg_table.md
            | table_item_1.md
            | table_item_2.md
            | table_item_3.md
         | examples
            | schema.yml
            | my_first_dbt_model.sql
            | my_first_dbt_model.sql
     | .gitignore
     | dbt_project.yml
```

Where `schema.yml` is something like:

```
version: 2

models:
    - name: my_first_dbt_model
      description: '{{ doc("agg_table") }}'
      columns:
          - name: id
            description: '{{ doc("table_item_1") }}'
            tests:
                - unique
                - not_null
```

So testing based on this model, I tried to use at least these options:

- the model reference notation as in [Link to another model in a description#](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/resource-properties/description#link-to-another-model-in-a-description)
- the docs block reference notation as in [Use a docs block in a description#](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/resource-properties/description#use-a-docs-block-in-a-description)

Which resulted in variations on:

Where `agg_table.md` is like:

```
{% docs agg_table %}

### Agg Table

| COLUMN\_NAME                   | DESCRIPTION                                                                   |
| ------------------------------ | ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
| table_item_1                   | {{ docs("table_item_1") }}                                                  |
| table_item_2                   | {{ docs("table_item_2") }}                                                  |
| table_item_3                   | {{ docs("table_item_3") }}                                                  |
| table_item_4                   | {{ docs("table_item_4") }}                                                  |
                    
{% enddocs %}
```

or

```
{% docs agg_table %}

### Agg Table

| COLUMN\_NAME                   | DESCRIPTION                                                                              |
| ------------------------------ | ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
| table_item_1                   | [first_model_description](#!/model/model.my_new_project.my_first_dbt_model#description)  |
| table_item_2                   | [first_model_columns](#!/model/model.my_new_project.my_first_dbt_model#columns)          |
| table_item_3                   | [table_item_doc](#!/docs/docs.my_new_project.table_item_3)                               |
| table_item_4                   | [table_item_doc](#!/docs/docs.my_new_project.table_item_4#description)                   |
                    

{% enddocs %}
```

But so far it looks like dbt is just completely missing the step of pre-processing markdown documents for jinja macros / references. The links are just pure HTML and not actually "compiling" any content.

Example result:
[image: markdown links]

Good feature to request on a github issue though.